# Why does the SearchTask show a prompt?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone 7 app I'm using a [SearchTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428723%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to show the results of a web page.  But every time I start the task I get the dread "Allow" screen.  I can imagine many users being scared to death by this...  Why do I need to be allowed to show the results of a web search result?  Is there anyway to avoid showing the scary popup screen?

Fwiw, here's my code:

```
SearchTask task = new SearchTask();
task.SearchQuery = "<my query>";
task.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt for the search app to use location will only be dislayed the first time the search app is used on the phone.

If you are seeing this displayed more than once is it because you are closing and restarting the emulator between uses of the task?
If not can you provide details of how to recreate the behaviour you're seeing.

The prompt is controlled by the search app and it is not possible to change the behaviour of that app. It is also an intent of the phone that apps should not be able to don something without the user knowing. By default the search app tries to use location to provide context when retrieving results. If the user has privcay concerns about their location data being used in this way they can prevent it. Hence this prompt.